# Sterile neutrinos on a theoretical point of view

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

The results at the [BEST](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14654) experiment strongly suggest that at least one "sterile neutrino" exist.
From the way the experiment is done it is obvious that only the lighter sterile neutrino can be observed.

My question on a purely theoretical point, and thus not a duplicate of related questions.

If the BEST experiment (or some other one) unambiguously proves the existence of one (light) sterile neutrino, is there a strong theoretical argument that implies that two more sterile neutrinos **must** exist, so there is one for each "family" ?

Comment: There could be a fourth family that includes the sterile neutrino.

Comment: No theoretical "arguments"--just conjectures and models. Sterile neutrinos are mostly inferred by disappearance, not appearance, so if your tank is leaking, you know there is at least one hole...